# crystal report formula sort string numerically

Tags: crystal-reports

i got a column of strings and i'm trying to sort it in crystal report

```
103
102
101-3
101-1
101-2
919
213-2
213-1A
111
213-1B
```

and i want to sort it this way

```
101-1
101-2
101-3
102
103
111
213-1A
213-1B
213-2
919
```

i've tried but with no luck

```
if IsNumeric({TableName.TextNum}) = false
then "0" & {TableName.TextNum} 
else NumericText(right({TableName.TextNum}, 1) 
then {TableName.TextNum}
```

glad with any help. tnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming their are no alphabets before `-`. Try this:

Create a formula and write below code:

```
ToNumber(Split(databasefield,'-')[1])
```

Use the above formula to sort, if not possible then create a group with the formula and then sort the group `ascending`

Comment: i will try it..i'll get back to you after i try it :)

Comment: @YoyieGuangco NP let me know incase any issue